# Cluster-autoscaler for Kind clusters

Tags: kubernetes, kind

I have been using Kind clusters for testing and simulating the behavior of my application, and it has been great so far. I would like to test some senarios involving cluater-autoscaler (CA) without actually spinning nodes in the cloud. The default Kubernetes cluster autoscaler (https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/cluster-autoscaler) doesn't work with Kind clusters.
Does a Kubernetes cluater-autoscaler exists for kind clusters?

Comment: Hi David Lifshiz welcome to S.F. I would suspect the answer is no, because I doubt anyone has coded up [a cluster api provider](https://cluster-api.sigs.k8s.io/reference/providers.html) for kind, although that does seem like an interesting technical challenge and certainly possible. Have you tried opening a ticket with either the cluster-api repo or kind itself, which I suspect would be the correct home?

Answer (score 1):

The answer appears to be: no.

According to [this](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind/issues/452#issuecomment-822758422) post Kind do not plan to allow adding/removing nodes to an existing cluster. Without the ability to change the number of nodes, a cluster autoscaler would be unnessacery.